# error occured when pulling messages

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

> google.gax.errors.GaxError: GaxError(RPC failed, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, User not authorized to perform this action.)>)

Why this type of error occurd when pulling emails from pub/sub API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because you/your app is not properly authenticated with gcloud:

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

This will output something like:

```
Credentials saved to file: $SOME_PATH/application_default_credentials.json
```

Then you have to set the env variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$SOME_PATH/application_default_credentials.json
```

Run the app

Hope this helps!